# Cloud vision API to extract or parse data from PDF

Tags: api, cloud, pdf-reader, vision-api

How can i use Google Cloud vision API to extract or parse data from PDF(my Input) and I need to save of the PDF content to Database and write some of the data to my HTML page , how can we do it?

Comment: anyone can help on this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use document_text_detection to extract data from your pdf files: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf